# Dynamically Update HashMap filled with Properties

Tags: java, properties, hashmap

**Scenario**:  Properties are stored in a config.properties file on local disk. These properties are read by Java application during startup and stored in a HashMap.

**Need**: Whenever someone changes the config.properties on local disk. I want my HashMap to be updated with these changes. As I need to perform some actions if these values change.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html

Comment: Perhaps look into something like [Archaius](https://github.com/Netflix/archaius).